# EWS Managed API, Get shared contacts group

Tags: .net, ews-managed-api

I'm struggling trying to find a way to do this, no luck so far. We were supposed to use EWS to connect to an account, read all the contacts that could be contained in there, and insert that data in a custom database. Pretty easy, i got it up and running soon without problems.

Now, once we have to take this to production, here comes the surprise. The customer refuses to give us the credentials of the account where the contacts will be stored. They say they'll only let us use a different account, and share the contacts to that account. Now, i have no problems to connect to EWS and get the contacts of the account i'm connecting with, but i see no way to obtain contacts when they dont belong to the account, but to a different one that is sharing them. Well, i know we could implement some impersionation, but i'm afraid that's not an option either...

Comment: I have a few questions about this configuration. What version of Exchange are you using? How are the contacts shared, are you using a shared mailbox or was the contacts folder shared to this other account? The more details you can give about the configuration the better chance we have to track down a resolution.

Comment: the Exchange version that is used in the production enviroment is 2013. The account has a set of contact folders defined. Those  contacts folders are shared. As i explained, we never had a problem during development, it all changed when once the production step came, unexpectedly our customer refused to allow us  to log into the account with the contacts, as previously expected. I'm aware that EWS supports impersonation, but that's not an option

Answer (score 0):

When you have shared contacts from another mailbox, those contacts are stored in a contacts folder within `WellKnownFolderName.Contacts`. Before you can access the contacts within this folder you need to get the `FolderId`. If you know the name of the shared contacts folder you can use something like this to find the correct folder.

```
Folder rootFolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);
foreach (Folder folder in rootFolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
{
  if (folder.DisplayName==DisplayName)
  {
    // Put your code here to get the FolderId and store it if necessary
  }
}
```

Now that you have the Id of the shared folder you should be able to use your code to collect contact information. I was able to get this working with a couple of mailboxes using Exchange Online.

I hope this helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark this post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---

Comment: Nope, this still gives me nothing. None of the items returned are the shared folders from the other mailbox, i just get contacts folders from the address i'm loged to exchange through the EWS...But thanks anyway

Comment: How was the contacts folder shared? Using Outlook you can share the folder and it sends a sharing invitation email. Another option is to set up delegate access to the mailbox. My approach above was using the Outlook sharing method.

Comment: as a sharing invitation email through outlook

Comment: When I did that with my tests I was able to see the contacts by using Outlook. Do you see the shared contacts in Outlook or Outlook Web App?

Comment: yeah, i do see them in Outlook, Outlook was never the problem